# Puzzled by failure of jQuery snippet for appending TDs to a TR

Tags: jquery

The motivation behind this question is to *understand why* the jQuery snippet below fails.

NOTE: by force of dumb, blind trial-and-error, I have found alternative code that does work (or seems to).  Therefore, the purpose of this question is not (per se) to "fix" the problem shown below.  Rather, my goal is to understand as much as I can *why* it fails.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
      var tds = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        var td = $('<td>');
        tds.push(td);
      }
      var $tds = $(tds);
      var $row1 = $('#row1');
      $tds.appendTo($row1);
    });
```

Basically, the intent of the snippet is to create three (jQuery-wrapped) `td` elements, and then to append them to a pre-existing `tr`.  (At the end of this post, I copy the full HTML+CSS+JS code.)

As stated before, my goal is to understand why this snippet fails.  Therefore, this question is primarily addressed to those who can already see, without running the code, that the snippet will fail.  To those of you who can do so: what is your reasoning?  what exactly tells you that the snippet can't work?

---

Here's the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
    td{width:100px;height:20px;background:#C40000}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr id="row1"></tr>
    </table>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
      var tds = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        var td = $('<td>');
        tds.push(td);
      }
      var $tds = $(tds);
      var $row1 = $('#row1');
      $tds.appendTo($row1);
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new jQuery object from an array of DOMElements, ***not*** from an array of `jQuery` objects, so this line is wrong:

```
var $tds = $(tds);
```

The simplest way to fix it would be by changing `$('<td>')` to `$('<td>')[0]`, to get an actual `<td>` DOMElement. You could also use `document.createElement('td')` there instead.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK jQuery cannot convert a array of jQuery wrappers to a single wrapper object, try this

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $tds = $();
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        var td = $('<td/>', {
            text: i
        });
        $tds = $tds.add(td);
    }
    var $row1 = $('#row1');

    $tds.appendTo($row1);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/D6RS9/)

Comment: Thank you much for the very helpful reply.  I wish I could choose both yours and Paulpro's.  It is rare in my experience that two such excellent answers show up almost simultaneously...